# Runtime error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" in android application

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing android application for control Lego NXT and connect ROS. I use library LeJos for control Lego. I'v got runtime error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" when run motor NXT from rosjava node:

```
class NXTNode implements NodeMain {
    public static RemoteMotor motor;

      @Override
      public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
        return new GraphName("android/NXTNode");
      }    
      @Override
      public void onStart(final Node node) {

        motor = new Motor().A;
            motor.setPower(60);  
            motor.forward();  

        node.executeCancellableLoop(new CancellableLoop() {
          @Override
          protected void setup() {
          }

          @Override
          protected void loop() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(10);
          }
        });
      }           
      @Override
      public void onShutdown(Node node) {
      }
      @Override
      public void onShutdownComplete(Node node) {
      }
    }
```

Node "NXTNode" I run in

```
  protected void init(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor) {
      NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration =    NodeConfiguration.newPublic(InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostAddress());
      nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(getMasterUri());
      nxt_node = new NXTNode();
      nodeMainExecutor.execute(nxt_node, nodeConfiguration);
  }
```

If I run motor from interface (onClick) then motor is running

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {                
    motor = new Motor().A;
    motor.setPower(60);
    motor.forward();
}
```

Where could be the problem?
Thank you!

UPDATE:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-7
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.NXTNode.onStart(NXTNode.java:239)
at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$1.run(DefaultNode.java:422)
at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$1.run(DefaultNode.java:419)
at org.ros.concurrent.ListenerCollection$1.run(ListenerCollection.java:108)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter$1.<init>(BluetoothAdapter.java:1012)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.<init>(BluetoothAdapter.java:1012)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(BluetoothAdapter.java:340)
at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommAndroid.search(NXTCommAndroid.java:394)
at lejos.pc.comm.NXTConnector.search(NXTConnector.java:171)
at lejos.pc.comm.NXTConnector.connectTo(NXTConnector.java:222)
at lejos.pc.comm.NXTConnector.connectTo(NXTConnector.java:39)
at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommandConnector.open(NXTCommandConnector.java:22)
at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommandConnector.getSingletonOpen(NXTCommandConnector.java:41)
at lejos.nxt.Motor.<clinit>(Motor.java:15)
... 7 more
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12997/runtime-error-%22can%27t-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper.prepare()%22-in-android-application/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2012-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-02-23**:
Could you post the full stack trace?

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-02-23**:
I updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved problem.
I added Looper.prepare() in method onStart.

```
public void onStart(final Node node) {
    Looper.prepare(); 
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0